# For AWS ASG, how to set up custom readiness check for new instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-ecs

We have an AutoScaling Group that runs containers (using ECS). When we add OR replace EC2 instances in the ASG, they don't have the docker images we want on them. So, we run a few `docker pull` commands using cloud-init to fetch the images when they boot up.

However, the ASG thinks that the new instance is ready, and terminates an old instance. But in reality, this new instance isn't ready until all docker images have been pulled.

---

E.g. 
Let's say my ASG's desired count is 5, and I have to pull 5 containers using cloud-init. Now, I want to replace all EC2 instances in my ASG.

As new instances start to boot up, ASG will terminate old instances. But due to the `docker pull` lag, there will be a time during the deploy, when the actual valid instances will be lesser than 3 or 2.

---

How can I "mark an instance ready" **only** when cloud-init is finished?

Note:I think Cloudformation can bridge this communication gap using CFN-Bootstrap. But I'm not using Cloudformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're look got is [AutoScaling Lifecycle Hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/lifecycle-hooks.html). You can keep an instance in the Pending:Wait state until you're docker pull has completed. You can then move the instance to InService. all of this can be done with the AWS CLI so it should be achievable with an AWS AutoScaling command before and after your docker commands.

The link to the documentation I have provided explains this feature in detail and provides great examples on how to use it.

Comment: This worked as expected!
Ansible tooling creates the lifecycle hook on the ASG. Then in the user-data, the EC2 instance performs the time consuming docker-pull commands, and then sends a continue signal to the ASG hook. ASG scaling/rolling continues!